# Call a function in another function. C#

Tags: c#, function

How can i call a function in another function?
Function as this:

```
static void controlla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to call ButtonClick Event handler?

Comment: if the function that calls the other function is static, then the "called" function has to be static

Answer (score 2):

Erm, like this:

```
static void controlla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SayHello();
}

static void SayHello()
{
  Console.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants to call `controlla_Click` which is one of the famoust newbie questions. Mostly the answer is: don't call an event handler but create another method which can be called from wherever.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call another button click event handler function you can try this:

```
static void controlla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
controllb_Click(sender,e);
}

static void controllb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
```